# Where do I need to place these viewport meta tags in my html and css files?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I put these tags at the end of my files but they don't work; where should they be placed in my files? HTML Tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and CSS Tag

```
@-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; }
```

Comment: the first one goes in the `<head>` section of your html the second one goes at the top of your css file

Comment: Thank you! At the very top of the css file? There's a body and container.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure but i don't think it even needs to be at the top. it should work no matter where you put it.

Answer (score 2):

Put the first code block between your header tags in your HTML :

`<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
</head>`

The second one should be placed on the top of your css file so it should be global.

Comment: Not a problem !

Answer (score 0):

Generally, meta elements (including viewport) should be placed in the document's `<head>`.

CSS rules should either be added to a CSS stylesheet and referenced with a `<link>` element or, if you're not using stylesheets for some reason, in a `<style>` element (also in the document's `<head>`).

Documentation for [head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head), [meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta), [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style), and [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) elements.

Comment: Thank you! I will use these extra resources.